# Merge small file into big file and give NaN's for the rows that do not match in python

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I would like to merge two data frames - big one and small one. Example of data frames is following:

```
# small data frame construction
>>> d1 = {'col1': ['A', 'B'], 'col2': [3, 4]}
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
>>> df1
   col1  col2
0     A     3
1     B     4

# big data frame construction
>>> d2 = {'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'col2': [3, 4, 6, 7, 8]}
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
>>> df2
   col1  col2
0     A     3
1     B     4
2     C     6
3     D     7
4     E     8
```

The code I am looking for should produce the following output (a data frame with big data frame shape, column names, and `NaN`s in rows that were not merged with the small data frame):

```
    col1   col2
0      A      3
1      B      4
2     NA     NA
3     NA     NA
4     NA     NA
```

The code I have tried:

```
>>> print(pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='right', sort=False))

  col1_x  col2_x col1_y  col2_y
0      A     3.0      A       3
1      B     4.0      B       4
2    NaN     NaN      C       5
3    NaN     NaN      D       6
4    NaN     NaN      E       7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameter `suffixes` with add `_` for added columns and then removed added columns with [`Series.str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html), inverted mask by `~` and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc`, because droping columns:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, 
              left_index=True, 
              right_index=True, 
              how='right', 
              sort=False, 
              suffixes=('','_'))
print (df)
  col1  col2 col1_  col2_
0    A   3.0     A      3
1    B   4.0     B      4
2  NaN   NaN     C      6
3  NaN   NaN     D      7
4  NaN   NaN     E      8

df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.endswith('_')]
print (df)
  col1  col2
0    A   3.0
1    B   4.0
2  NaN   NaN
3  NaN   NaN
4  NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but it did not give the answer I was looking for. I am looking to something similar to a vlookup that provides both NA's and values. For some reason the that end result did not pop up as a column, even when both dataframes share the same name columns. Thank you for attempting

Comment: @SolomonRichberg - Ok, can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? Because if use `left_index=True, right_index=True` in merge it working with index values - not sure if need it. Maybe the best should be add 1,2 small sample df for explain more.